# Can we replace custom tokens in PDF using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, csv

I am creating a small application which manipulates PDF file as follows

- A customer creates a CSV to a given specification that contains the
  name,address, country, ink type, station to use. This CSV could also 
  include customized tokens which  replace tokens that are written
  within their PDF Document.
- A customer creates a PDF document it could be a standard document
  that's exactly the same that gets sent to everyone in their CSV file,
  or it could contain special tokens  which are replace with specific
  contacts details within the CSV.

I've briefly looked at http://us.php.net/pdf and FPDF, but I was wondering what specific technique I'd use to achieve this.

I was thinking I'd insert an address tokens string where I want the address to go, and then use some function to update those tokens in the PDF document.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have php experience, but not with editing / generating pdf documents from php.

Comment: use http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php it is very flexible and you can create wonderful PDF's with custom designs .

Answer (score 4):

You can use [MPDF lib](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php?page=Download) to generate PDF. In it you just need to pass your HTML content.

Answer (score 1):

From half the PHP devs I talk to they recommend this:

http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/setapdf-linkreplacer/

For your problem - I believe you need to buy it but there is an eval copy for your devving needs.

HTHs - Thanks,
//P

Answer (score 1):

I am using Tcpdf library to generate pdf.

please check url for example. http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

Answer (score 0):

If you kept all the contact information on a single page you could use poppler-utils https://packages.debian.org/sid/poppler-utils to pdfmerge the page of contact info with the bulk of the PDF. Use tcpdf library to create the one page with contact info.